# import matplotlib from jupyter notebook fails, while command line python interactive mode works

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using venv,

```
python --version
   Python 3.6.1
pip3 version: 
   pip 9.0.1 from /Users/zhiyin/ml/venv3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

`import matplotlib` works in python shell.

However, in jupyter mode, it fails with the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d1ff1f5634e7> in <module>()
          1 # Render our plots inline
    ----> 2 get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')
          3 
          4 import pandas as pd
          5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in magic(self, arg_s)
       2144         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
       2145         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
    -> 2146         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
       2147 
       2148     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
       2065                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
       2066             with self.builtin_trap:
    -> 2067                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
       2068             return result
       2069 

    <decorator-gen-107> in matplotlib(self, line)

    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
        185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
        186     def magic_deco(arg):
    --> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
        188 
        189         if callable(arg):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.py in matplotlib(self, line)
         97             print("Available matplotlib backends: %s" % backends_list)
         98         else:
    ---> 99             gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui)
        100             self._show_matplotlib_backend(args.gui, backend)
        101 

    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in enable_matplotlib(self, gui)
       2916         """
       2917         from IPython.core import pylabtools as pt
    -> 2918         gui, backend = pt.find_gui_and_backend(gui, self.pylab_gui_select)
       2919 
       2920         if gui != 'inline':

    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in find_gui_and_backend(gui, gui_select)
        267     """
        268 
    --> 269     import matplotlib
        270 
        271     if gui and gui != 'auto':

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Comment: In Python shell, and in jupyter, what is the value of `sys.path`?

Comment: os.environ, shell:'PATH': '/Users/zhiyin/ml/venv3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Users/zhiyin/Library/meld-osx-9:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'

Comment: os.environ, PATH in Jupyter notebook, 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:
/Users/zhiyin/ml/venv3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:
/Users/zhiyin/Library/meld-osx-9:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'

Comment: in shell: sys.path is: 
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/Users/zhiyin/ml/venv3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages']

Comment: in jupyter, sys.path is:  
['',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/Users/zhiyin/.ipython']

Comment: I see that jupyter sys.path does not contain `/Users/zhiyin/ml/venv3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.  Try adding that directory to the jupyter path.